# Why is BIGENDIAN a directive if it's not resolved at compile-time?

Tags: c#, .net, c-preprocessor, directive, endianness

Excuse the poor wording, but I couldn't find a better way to explain it.

From my understanding, C# is a WORA language- you can write it on one machine and deploy it on another, because the MSIL isn't compiled until the application is actually run.

So then why is it that `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` is defined [like so](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/BitConverter.cs#L31-L35):

```
#if BIGENDIAN
    public static readonly bool IsLittleEndian /* = false*/;
#else
    public static readonly bool IsLittleEndian = true;
#endif
```

`BIGENDIAN` here is a preprocessor directive, which means that it's resolved at compile-time. So if the developer's machine is little endian, and the target uses big endian, **will `IsLittleEndian` still report `true` on the target machine?**

Comment: `BIGENDIAN` is a preprocessor symbol, not a directive.  `#if` is the directive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it will work as expected. The reason it'll work is because the .NET runtime installed on the target system was built/compiled for that target system, so it's `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian` property will return `false`. Your code is simply referencing that property, so it isn't determined until runtime.

Comment: The property is a compile time one `#if BIGENDIAN` so there is no property to reference at run time.

Comment: Your code will reference that property using `BitConverter.IsLittleEndian`. Even when it is compiled, it still is referencing that property, not hard-coded to `true/false` in your app (it **is** hard-coded in the runtime, which is why each architecture would have its own version of the runtime). This is due to the property being defined as `static readonly` rather than `const`. If it was `const`, then you would be correct: it would not be a property reference.

Comment: Won't this go wrong if you take a copy of the dll compiled to byte code on one machine and coppy it to a different one? I thought the whole point of using byte code was that .Net dlls are supposed to be portable after compilation.

Comment: No, it will still work. That compiled dll is referencing the property (not the boolean value of that property) defined in the .NET dll. When you move it to another architecture, it ends up referencing that system's .NET dll.